# AWS CDK installation issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, aws-cdk

I have tried to install AWS CDK in my local system, using this command "npm install -g aws-cdk" getting installed successfully, but when I am checking version with cdk --version i am getting Microsoft JScript compilation error

```
Script : C:\Users\170905\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\bin\cdk.js
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: Invalid Character
Code: 800A03F6
Source: Microsoft Jscript compilation error
```

Comment: Changing pointer of "open with" in cdk.js properties (right click file and goto properties) with nodejs (for me it was in program files) worked.

Answer (score 2):

set the path using below command and try.

```
**setx PATH "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm"**
```

or directly navigate to this path and open cmd. It will work.